# Enlazar un componente distinto por elemento generado dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Estoy hace mucho intentando hacer un ng repeat que por cada elemento repetido inserte un componente, estuve inspeccionando con track by $index, pero no tengo exito..
mi codigo es el siguiente:

html

```
<div class="benefit" ng-repeat='benefit in $ctrl.benefits track by $index'>
    <div class="benefit-description">
        <p class='percentage'>{{benefit.porcentaje}}</p>
        <p class="percentage-detail">{{benefit.title}}.</p>
        <p class="partner">
            <span><img src="app/assets/avatar.png" class="partner-min"></span>
            <span class="partner-name">{{benefit.partnet}}</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="partner-brand">
        <img src="app/assets/greyimg.png" class="partner-avatar" width="91">
    </div>

    <durability-component></durability-component> 
    <request-component></request-component>
    <favorite-benefit-component></favorite-benefit-component>
</div>
```

y mi componente:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
        angular
            .module('benefit')
            .component('benefitComponent', {
                bindings: {},
                templateUrl : 'app/benefit/benefit.html',
                controller : benefitCtrl
            })



            function benefitCtrl($scope){

                this.benefits = [
                    {porcentaje: '0%', title: 'orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing', partner:'juan'},
                    {porcentaje: '0%', title: 'orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting', partner:'pedro'},
                    {porcentaje: '0%', title: 'orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and type', partner:'luis'}
                ]
            }
}());
```

O sea, el primer div que se repita, deberia tener solamente el durability-component, el segundo el request y el tercero favorite...
He intentando con ng if y ng show, pero no lo puedo sacar.. no se que propiedad deberia utilizar para poder lograrlo y no quiero tener codido repetido solo por esta partecita. Acpeto sugerencias.
desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo solucione poniendole a cada componente un numero al index

```
<durability-component ng-if="$index == 0" ></durability-component> 
<request-component ng-if="$index == 1" ></request-component>
<favorite-benefit-component ng-if="$index == 2"></favorite-benefit-component>
```

Gracias a todos igual :)